# Azure Mobile Service - Android hangs when trying to execute table query

Tags: android, azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services

I have created new MobileServiceClient. I'm able to login by configured identity provider and getting table works correct.

```
mUserLoginTable = mClient.getTable("User_Login", UserLogin.class);
```

Problem happens when i try to check if logged user exists in my table.

1st version:

```
mUserLoginTable.where().field("facebook_id").eq(_user.getUserId()).execute().get();
```

2nd version:

```
public boolean ChekIfGoogeUserExists() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){
                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        List<UserLogin> result;
                    ListenableFuture<MobileServiceList<UserLogin>> future  = mUserLoginTable.where().field("google_id").eq(_user.getUserId()).execute();
                        return future.get().isEmpty();
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            };
           return  runAsyncTask(task).get();

    }
```

Nothing seems to work, android just hangs please help!

I have created User_Login table in my azure database with SqlServer. Then I added Azure MobileService EasyTable with "User_Login" name. It properly found and mapped User_Login table from database (columns were auto added). Right now access is set to anonymous.

I have olso defined read function for User_Login in AppServiceEditor:

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();
table.read(function (context) {
     return context.execute();
 });
```

(Having it commented out by default olso dosen't help)

Comment: Add a trace of the backend - what do the logs say when you turn on verbose diagnostic logging?  Also, use fiddler or similar to see the communication - what is the request and response in question?

Comment: @Groth Seems that there is not any query operations in the code for `User_Login` edited in AppServiceEditor. Any update?

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems. 
1st One i used 
`.inputfield("facebook_id")` 
correct one seems to be 
`.inputfield(val("facebook_id"))`
2nd I perfomed network operation on main thresd by using 
`.get()` 
and it caused freeeze in android app. Thanks for help!